# Add time modified to filename with PHP and .htaccess to force fresh caching

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I have followed this (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/force-reload-css-javascript-unique-filenames/) tutorial to force an update of the caching by dynamically naming my css and javascript files by adding the time modified to the filename. This is for use during development as I am having issues with my hosting caching my files serverside. I have confirmed that  mod_rewrite is on and htaccess is being read, I am definately on an apache server. I get no errors in my script but when I inspect the source with developer tools the filename has not changed. The test page is www.diysoakwells.com.au/cart2.php.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^diysoakwells.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.diysoakwells.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*)\.[0-9]+\.(.*)$ /$1/$2.$3 [L]


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Don’t compress
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary

#Dealing with proxy servers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

</IfModule> 

<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

PHP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles2.1<?php echo filemtime('/css/styles2.1.css'); ?>.css" />


<script language="javascript" src="/js/simpleCart_verify<?php echo filemtime('/js/simpleCart_verify.js'); ?>.js"></script>
```

I have tried the solution in the comments but it all looks fine to me, does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making it unnecessarily complicated. Instead of modifying the filename, you can add a query variable. That would force a reload as well and requires no rewriting of your assets filenames:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles2.1.css?ts=<?php echo filemtime('/path/to/css/styles2.1.css'); ?>" />
// etc.
```

And as long as you send the same query variable, the result will be cached as well.

Comment: This is interesting, what would be the benefit of the method in the tutorial then or is it just out of date? edit:

Comment: @JPB The only thing I can think of are browsers that really refuse to reload a file with a query variable / insist on caching it. But I have never encountered one so as far as I am concerned it is unnecessarily complicated. This trick is very old as well, so it's not related to that.

Comment: As an addendum to this solution I am renaming all my .html files to .php including index.html so I can add PHP scripts as necessary. My research indicates this will not have any effect on my SEO and is an accepted practice. Do you agree?

Comment: @JPB No, if you change the file-name, that will definitely have an effect on SEO. You would need to setup 301 redirects in your .htaccess file to avoid loosing positioning.

Comment: What about a brand new site?

Comment: @JPB You mentioned SEO :-) If there is nothing yet, you are right, there is no difference between .html and .php.

Comment: Great, I guess I was mainly thinking about load times or requests to the server having an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to add a `?t=` after the file path so your time is added as a query on the URL.

Secondly, the path called in the `filemtime` function looks like an absolute file path on your file system. Use `file_exists()` to make sure `/css/styles2.1.css` actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am abandoning my method in favour of jeroen's simple solution.