# How to reload the html dom using the current time?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Is there any way to reload the HTML all elements with the current time.
I am using the yii2 framework.
May be there is some solution in jquery.
Please give me some idea.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `with the current time` ? is it dynamic ?

Comment: means some time i add a new element like an image in the dom , on page refresh first time it is not loading until clear the cache! so i want to clear the cashe with current time. yes it is dynamic

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking.  From the above comment I think you might be asking about how do you specify client side caching of items such as images?  If that's the case there are a number of HTTP headers you can send to specify how long things should be cached for, but you really need to rewrite your question to make it clear what you really want and why.

Comment: You can set these cache clear values in your .htaccess file so the page would load new content from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for a yii project. The simplest solution is to append the timestamp as a parameter at the end of the element url:

Under directory **assets/AppAsset.php**

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        foreach ($this->css as $key => $value) {
            $this->css[$key] = $value . '?t=' . filemtime($this->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        }
        foreach ($this->js as $key => $value) {
            $this->js[$key] = $value . '?t=' . filemtime($this->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        }
    }
}
```

or in your views:

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::getAlias('@web'); ?>/paris.jpg?t=<?php echo filemtime(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'paris.jpg'); ?>" />
```

I had done this using a view helper. If I find the code I will post it later.
Unfortunately you cannot use this for resources loaded through css(eg. background images) or javascript files.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35723982/4448410), it actually the same solution.